# How to use tilesloaded event for google maps v3

Tags: jquery-ui, events, google-maps-api-3, jquery-events

Here I have a code:

```
<script>

$(function() {
    $( "#photo" ).resizable();
  $( "#photo" ).draggable({revert: 'invalid'});
    $( "#left" ).droppable({
      accept: '#photo',
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        $( this )
          .find( "p" )
            .html( "Dropped!" );
      }
    });
  });    
    </script>
```

and this code I must run after full loading google maps, so I need to "hook up" tilesloaded event for this code.

http://jsbin.com/ayugun/7/edit

But how to do that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is the code

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'tilesloaded', function() {
  doWhatYouWant();
});
```