# Javascript Google Maps refresh issue - Grey Tiles Displayed

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, refresh

I have been facing grey tiles problem in google map api v3. I have gmap and there are so many markers on it. Grey tiles appeared very frequently when zoom in/out or drag the map. I have been searching for the solution but did not find which will fix the problem. I have tried resize, tilesloaded, idle events to somehow change the center of the map, still no luck.
I could not find a way to know whether all tiles have been loaded or not. tilesloaded fires only when all tiles are loaded.

So far I have looked at following links:

- [How to use tilesloaded event for google maps v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17122928/how-to-use-tilesloaded-event-for-google-maps-v3)
- [Google Maps API v3 Loading Only After Page Refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19651008/google-maps-api-v3-loading-only-after-page-refresh)
- [Grey boxes appear in parts of embedded Google Map in modal box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8812268/grey-boxes-appear-in-parts-of-embedded-google-map-in-modal-box)
- https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=1448

Any help in this regards is appreciated...
Thanks, Ash

Comment: Put up a jsfiddle that reproduces the problem and we will look at it.

Comment: This is a big project contains so many dependencies on so many things. I understand this is difficult to answer based on information i have provided. Will check if I can create some sample code.

Comment: Turned out to be a problem in my machine only. All other machine does not have any issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue of not centring, and displays only part of map on map canvas.
This line fixed my problem:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
```

Put it after

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker({...});
```

before

```
map.setCenter(myLatlng);
map.setZoom(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

to replac with:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  initialize();
});
```